# How do you assign a QML Item to a component property in QML and then use that object inside the component?

Tags: properties, qml

I'm trying to create a QML object that acts like a wrapper for other objects.  Here's my QML file (Container.qml):

```
Item {
    property string label
    property Item control

    Row {
        Label {
            text: label
        }

        // Not sure how to display the control assigned to the control property
    }
}
```

What I would like to do (in my QML that consumes this component) is something like this:

```
Container {
    label: "My Label"
    control: Textbox {
        text: "My Value"
    }
}
```

When fed that QML the result (in the interface) should be something resembling the output from this QML:

```
Item {
    Row {
        Label {
            text: "My Label"
        }
        Textbox {
            text: "My Value"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible?  When I try to do this I get "cannot assign object to property" when assigning an Item to the control property.  I've searched the Qt forums and Googled this mercilessly, but no success.  If anybody knows the answer it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Jack

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can dynamically load items using the [Loader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-loader.html) element, and then set the 'control' property to be an [alias](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qml-extending-types.html#property-aliases) that directly refers to the loader's *sourceComponent* property.

So your Container.qml could look like this:

```
Item {
    property string label
    property alias control : loader.sourceComponent

    width: 200; height: 200

    Row {
        Label { text: label }
        Loader { id: loader }
    }
}
```

Now when you assign a graphical item to the 'control' property, it will automatically be displayed by the Loader.

Comment: Wow, that Loader object looks great!  Wish I would have known about that a long time ago!  That is a much more elegant solution.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 44):

There is much better solution:

```
/* MyObject.qml */

Rectangle {
    default property alias data /* name can be any */ : inner_space.data

    /* ... You can put other elements here ... */
    Item {
       id: inner_space

       /* ... Params ... */
    }
    /* ... You can put other elements here ... */
}
```

And now we can do all we want!

```
/* main.qml */

Rectangle {
    MyObject {
        Button {
             /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to user [bobbaluba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/652702/bobbaluba) for suggesting to use the `data` property rather than `children`.

Comment: Does this work for non visual items, like TableViewColumn? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527103/how-propagate-tableviewcolumn-list-to-child-tableview

Comment: "Thanks to user bobbaluba for suggesting to use the data property rather than children."

for me only `children` worked, I was trying to create a generic item delegate and with `parent` it wasn't treated as part of the item

Comment: Note: For corrected showing inner content, after "id: inner_space" necessary append: "width: inner_space.childrenRect.width" and "height: inner_space.childrenRect.height".

Answer (score 2):

You can create a container for other items using a custom property:

```
Item
{
    id: root

    property list<Item> rectList: [
        Rectangle
        {
            parent: root
        },
        Rectangle
        {
            parent: root
        },
        Rectangle
        {
            parent: root
        },
        Rectangle
        {
            parent: root
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that the parent of the Rectangle Items is set manually so they will be visual children of the container.

You can assess them as a javascript array

```
for ( var i = 0; i < root.rectList.length; i++ )
{
   var rect = root.rectList[i];
   rect.visible = true;
}
```

or

```
rect.rectList[1].visible = false;
```

Comment: This actually works - I never expected we could use "templated lists" in QML - where did you find this? Is this documented *anywhere* ???

Comment: It's not documented specifically that I recall. It's emergent from the design and integration of javascript with QObject. The specifics about the assigned parent I had to learn by trial and error though

Answer (score 1):

Been using QML for about a month now, no idea really how to do this I'm afraid.

Best plan is to figure out all possible things that the control (`Textbox` in your example) could be, create an instance of each component in your row, and set a corresponding state on your `Item`.  The state would then take care of making the desired component visible or invisible as appropriate.

**Edit**

Just thought.  (Haven't tried this but give it a go!)  In your `Item`'s `Component.onCompleted:` handler, try calling `control.createObject(rowID)` where `rowID` is an `id` for your `Row` object, (which you want to be the parent of `control`).

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The solution (as I understand it) would work, but is less than ideal.  All of those extra hidden controls just to render one control...seems like a waste.  I'll keep plugging away.  If I find anything I'll be sure to post back.

Comment: That certainly seems like it should work.  I misunderstood the documentation on dynamically creating objects.  Your brief explanation clarifies that for me.  I'm still getting the `"cannot assign object to property"` error though.  It doesn't make sense, because I know you [can assign Items to properties](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-extending-types.html).  For example, the rectangle accepts a Gradient (not an Item, I know, but an Object).  I think your answer is correct, I just don't understand why this won't work! :)  Thanks for your help!  If you have more insights, let me know!