# How propagate TableViewColumn list to child TableView?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm trying to make custom component for editable tables in QML, like this:

```
// BaseTableView.qml
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

Item {
    signal addActionPerformed()
    signal editActionPerformed(int id)
    signal deleteActionPerformed(int id)

    property var model

    ToolBar {
        id: toolBar
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right

        Row {
            ToolButton {
                id: addButton
                iconSource: "qrc:/icons/actions/add.png"
                onClicked: addActionPerformed()
            }

            ToolButton {
                id: editButton
                enabled: false
                iconSource: "qrc:/icons/actions/edit.png"
            }

            ToolButton {
                id: deleteButton
                enabled: false
                iconSource: "qrc:/icons/actions/delete.png"
            }
        }
    }

    TableView {
        id: tableView
        model: parent.model
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: toolBar.bottom
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        onCurrentRowChanged: {
            editButton.enabled = currentRow !== null
            deleteButton.enabled = currentRow !== null
        }
    }
}
```

and use this component in another file like this:

```
// Another.qml file
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

import "../common" // Here is BaseTableView.qml

BaseTableView {

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "id"
        title: qsTr("Id")
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        role: "object_expression"
        title: qsTr("Expression")
    }
}
```

So, problem is how i can pass table view columns from usage to underlying TableView?
I've tried to make property list in BaseTableView and assign a list of objects to this property in Aother.qml? but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [default properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#default-properties):

> An object definition can have a single default property. A default property is the property to which a value is assigned if an object is declared within another object's definition without declaring it as a value for a particular property.

More relevant for your scenario:

> You will notice that child objects can be added to any Item-based type without explicitly adding them to the children property. This is because the default property of Item is its data property, and any items added to this list for an Item are automatically added to its list of children.
>   Default properties can be useful for reassigning the children of an item. See the TabWidget Example, which uses a default property to automatically reassign children of the TabWidget as children of an inner ListView.

If you take a look at the [TabWidget example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-customitems-tabwidget-tabwidget-qml.html) that the last paragraph refers to, you should have all you need:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: tabWidget

    // Setting the default property to stack.children means any child items
    // of the TabWidget are actually added to the 'stack' item's children.
    // See the "Property Binding"
    // documentation for details on default properties.
    default property alias content: stack.children

    property int current: 0

    onCurrentChanged: setOpacities()
    Component.onCompleted: setOpacities()

    function setOpacities() {
        for (var i = 0; i < stack.children.length; ++i) {
            stack.children[i].opacity = (i == current ? 1 : 0)
        }
    }

    Row {
        id: header

        Repeater {
            model: stack.children.length
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: tabWidget.width / stack.children.length; height: 36

                Rectangle {
                    width: parent.width; height: 1
                    anchors { bottom: parent.bottom; bottomMargin: 1 }
                    color: "#acb2c2"
                }
                BorderImage {
                    anchors { fill: parent; leftMargin: 2; topMargin: 5; rightMargin: 1 }
                    border { left: 7; right: 7 }
                    source: "tab.png"
                    visible: tabWidget.current == index
                }
                Text {
                    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter; verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    text: stack.children[index].title
                    elide: Text.ElideRight
                    font.bold: tabWidget.current == index
                }
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: tabWidget.current = index
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: stack
        width: tabWidget.width
        anchors.top: header.bottom; anchors.bottom: tabWidget.bottom
    }
}
```

In cases like this, where you want to replicate something that is done by an item offered by Qt, it can also be helpful to take a look at the [source code of what you're trying to replicate](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtquickcontrols/source/5fbad0e976b4b603e2f4faccbcb5c052d917ba7a:src/controls/TableView.qml). However, the documentation is a bit easier to read. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot... Works with "default property alias content: tableView.data"