# Adding Items to a layout of a custom component

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a custom `Footer` `Component` which I would like to reuse in different place in my QML App:

```
Rectangle {
    color: "gold"
    height: 50
    anchors {
        bottom: parent.bottom
        left: parent.left
        right: parent.right
    }

    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10

        Button {
            text: "quit"
        }
    }
}
```

The use of this is easy:

```
Window {
    visible: true

    Footer {
    }
}
```

But now I would like to add a "ButtonA" to the `RowLayout` of my `Footer` in one view and a "ButtonB" in another view.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527103/how-propagate-tableviewcolumn-list-to-child-tableview/26535543#26535543) answer.

You have to declare a `default` property in `Footer.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle {
    color: "gold"
    height: 50

    default property alias content: rowLayout.children

    anchors {
        bottom: parent.bottom
        left: parent.left
        right: parent.right
    }

    RowLayout {
        id: rowLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10

        Button {
            text: "quit"
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures that any items declared as children of `Footer` instances will be added to its `RowLayout`.

**`main.qml`**:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: viewAComponent
    }

    Component {
        id: viewAComponent

        Rectangle {
            id: viewA
            color: "salmon"

            Footer {
                id: footerA

                Button {
                    text: "Go to next view"
                    onClicked: stackView.push(viewBComponent)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: viewBComponent

        Rectangle {
            id: viewB
            color: "lightblue"

            Footer {
                id: footerB

                Button {
                    text: "Go to previous view"
                    onClicked: stackView.pop()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used [`StackView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html) as a convenient way of navigating between the views.

Comment: This is a very similar way I'm doing it now. But I don't want to have to anchor the new buttons so that they look an behave like they are in the same layout as the button in my reusable footer. That is kind of messy. Therefore I'm looking for a way to add them to the footers layout...

Comment: I see. Updated answer.