# ExclusiveGroup as property won't work

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a custom `Footer` `Component` which has a `RowLayout` to which children (`Button`s) can be added following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31615973/3095014) approach.

Now I want the `Button`s to be checkable, but only one `Button` should be checked at a time. So I defined an `ExclusiveGroup` added the *internal* `Footer` `Button`s. *This works*. Only one of these `Button`s can be checked at a time.

To add the *external* buttons to the same `ExclusiveGroup` I added a property which exposes it. But this *doesn't* work. I get this errors:

> qrc:/main.qml:13:20: Unable to assign [undefined] to QQuickExclusiveGroup*
>   qrc:/main.qml:19:20: Unable to assign [undefined] to QQuickExclusiveGroup*

This is the code:

**main.qml**

```
Window {
    visible: true

    Footer {
        Button {
            text: "extern 1"
            checkable: true
            exclusiveGroup: parent.radioInputGroup
        }

        Button {
            text: "extern 2"
            checkable: true
            exclusiveGroup: parent.exclusiveGroup
        }
    }
}
```

**Footer.qml**

```
Rectangle {
    color: "gold"
    height: 50

    default property alias content: rowLayout.children

    anchors {
        bottom: parent.bottom
        left: parent.left
        right: parent.right
    }

    RowLayout {
        id: rowLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 10
        property var exclusiveGroup: radioInputGroup

        ExclusiveGroup {
            id: radioInputGroup
        }
        Button {
            id: button
            text: "intern 1"
            checkable: true
            exclusiveGroup: radioInputGroup
        }

        Button {
            text: "intern 2"
            checkable: true
            exclusiveGroup: radioInputGroup
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work to me except for the `Button` with text `extern 1`. You have to change the `exclusiveGroup` from `parent.radioInputGroup` to `parent.exclusiveGroup`.

Comment: I'm a little bit blind today :-/ Thank you!