# Re-using Component of TextField responding to wheel events, with signal handling

Tags: qt, qml

I enriched a TextField (displaying a float) so that it can be changed by mouse wheel, all while being still editable by hand.

I found the quirk with `forceActiveFocus` and `onClicked` [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtquick-components-symbian-1.1/qml-textfield.html#custom-buttons-to-textfield) (I wish I could just let all events pass down the widget stack like in Qt) and use `onWheel` to change the value (please let me know if this is not the best way to do this):

```
TextField{
   text: cxxObject.floatAttribute.toString()
   onEditingFinished: { cxxObject.floatAttribute=parseFloat(text); }
   MouseArea{
      anchors.fill: parent
      propagateComposedEvent: true
      onClicked: { parent.forceActiveFocus(); }
      onWheel: { parent.text=parseFloat(parent.text)-.5*wheel.angleDelta.y/120;
         parent.editingFinished();
      }
   }
```

I would like to re-use this component instead of TextField in several places (without copy&paste), so I tried to declare the component like this:

```
Component{
    id: wheeledFloatTextField
    property real initValue: 0.
    property real dWheel: 0.5
    signal editingFinished(real value);
    TextField{
        text: parent.initValue.toString();
        // re-emit signal to the component
        // so that user-defined slot can be defined when re-used
        onEditingFinished: parent.editingFinished(parseFloat(text));
        // validator: ...
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            propagateComposedEvents: true
            onClicked: { parent.forceActiveFocus();  }
            onWheel: {
                parent.text=parseFloat(parent.text)-parent.parent.dWheel*wheel.angleDelta.y/120;
                parent.editingFinished();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and re-use:

```
Loader{
    sourceComponent: wheeledFloatTextField
    initValue: cxxObject.floatAttribute;
    onEditingFinished: { cxxObject.floatAttribute=value; }
}
```

I am however getting (at the line where `Component` is used):

```
Component objects cannot declare new properties.
```

What is wrong? I was some posts (like [How do you assign a QML Item to a component property in QML and then use that object inside the component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021350/how-do-you-assign-a-qml-item-to-a-component-property-in-qml-and-then-use-that-ob#10031214) and https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/dev/custom_components/index.html) from which I am gathering I might need to wrap the inside of `Component` (which is as-if it were a separate `.qml` file and does not define a scope) in something like `Item` or `Container` but I am not sure what to do. Any hint?

I would like to keep the definition inline first, later move to a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the component declared in a separate file, you can (should) omit the top-level `Component`. For maximum reusability of components, it is reccomended to declare them in a separate file.
A `Component` can not have any properties declared. It is basically stopping the object creation in a prototypical state. That is useful if you want to configure the object, for later creation, for example lazy initialization (delegates).
If you have a property of type `Component` and you use the `myProp: SomeType {...}` syntax, it will automatically just create a component from that.

I think the best solution is to put your TextField in a seperate file, and add the properties to the root-node so it is customizable.

File1 (e.g. "CustomTextField.qml")

```
TextField{
    property real initValue: 0.
    property real dWheel: 0.5
    signal editingFinished(real value);
    text: initValue.toString();
    // re-emit signal to the component
    // so that user-defined slot can be defined when re-used
    onEditingFinished: editingFinished(parseFloat(text));
    // validator: ...
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        onClicked: { parent.forceActiveFocus();  }
        onWheel: {
            parent.text=parseFloat(parent.text)-parent.parent.dWheel*wheel.angleDelta.y/120;
            parent.editingFinished();
        }
    }
}
```

You can then reuse the Component in all known ways like in a Loader:

```
Loader {
    sourceComponent: CustomTextField { // Property type is component, so it automatically creates a Component instead of the full-blown object, until it is loaded.
        initValue: 12
        dWheel: 42
    }
    ...
}
```

or without Loader

```
CustomTextField {
    ...
}
```

---

Of course you can keep it inline, but even then, you have to add the properties to the root-element *inside* the `Component`.

```
Component {
    id: componentId // only thing you can set besides one Object in a Component
    TextField{
        id: componentRoot // You can't reference this id from outside the Component!!!
        property real initValue: 0.
        property real dWheel: 0.5
        signal editingFinished(real value);
        text: initValue.toString();
        // re-emit signal to the component
        // so that user-defined slot can be defined when re-used
        onEditingFinished: editingFinished(parseFloat(text));
        // validator: ...
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            propagateComposedEvents: true
            onClicked: { parent.forceActiveFocus();  }
            onWheel: {
                parent.text=parseFloat(parent.text)-parent.parent.dWheel*wheel.angleDelta.y/120;
                parent.editingFinished();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This has the down-side that you will always need a separate object to instantiate the Component, like a `Loader` which adds overhead and complicates communication in the file between the objects, since to address it, you will need to use: `loaderId.item.property` which might be expensive in lookup, you need to ensure that `item` is defined e.t.c.